# Making localhost accessible from the internet

Tags: web, localhost

I don't know where to place this question. I feel this isn't the right place for this kind of question.
 I am new to this stackexchange site.
Really, really excuse me for the question you are about to read.

i made a server but it's localhost at 127.0.0.1. How to make it on the web, to be accessible from the outside, or at least the LAN network, not only on my PC ?
I tried many different ways by myself, just by guessing and i screw everything up multiple times, and again unninstalling and installing wamp.
The software pack i am using is WAMP and i want to install phpbb.

Comment: You are right, this isn't the right place. Voting to migrate it to [su].

Answer (score 0):

What service you want to access from outside/web you will need below things in order to access services from outside/web

1. Public ip on server
2. open ports in firewall if any
3. service runing on server to serve the request
4. proper configuration of application or service on server which will be accessed from outside/web

if your are runing web service (apache,httpd) the you have to open port 80, if  https then port 443, also you should have apache service runing and pointed to proper the directory

Also if you are using a basic router then you need to open port or forward ports to respective server

example:
you have a server with apache runing on ip 192.168.1.5 in your lan segment and public ip of your router is xx.xxx.xx.xx then you need to do settings in router which will allow any traffic coming on public ip xx.xxx.xx.xx port 80 to be forwarded to 192.168.1.5 then only you can access your apache page from outside/web

Similar way for different services you have different ports

Answer (score 0):

Check https://ngrok.com/, it's a service that does exactly that. The more traditional way is to get sharing hosting, or even a full VPS somewhere, and host your site.